# Extracting elements in Scrapy to different fields

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and was trying to scrape some images from one of my suppliers site.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="image-additional caruofredsel-additional">
  <a href="http://scssports.in/image/cache/data/adidas-t-t-husgado-white-unisex-sports-shoes-g40422-500x500.jpg" title="Adidas T T Husgado Badminton and Squash Shoes" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"><img class="fade-image" 
src="http://scssports.in/image/cache/data/adidas-t-t-husgado-white-unisex-sports-shoes-g40422-80x80.jpg" title="Adidas T T Husgado Badminton and Squash Shoes" alt="Adidas T T Husgado Badminton and Squash Shoes" />
</a>
```

As you can see there are two image urls there. I have created two differents fields in the items.py file namely imgurl1 and imgurl2 since I want those two different images to be stored under different columns when I export them to csv.

Is there any way I can  do so?

My code:

```
titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='image-additional caruofredsel-additional']")
      items = []
      for titles in titles:
            item = SampleItem()
            item ["imgurl2"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `<img>` tag is inside the `<a>` tag, this should work

```
item ["imgurl1"] = titles.select("a/img/@src").extract()
```